# character '\0' vs string "\0"

Tags: c++, c

An online testing system expects my code to output the number `10`.

It accepts:

```c
printf("%d",10)
printf("%c%c\0", '1', '0')
printf("%c%c\0something", '1', '0')
printf("%c%c%s", '1', '0', "\0")
```

But rejects:

```c
printf("%c%c%c", '1', '0', '\0')
printf("%c%c%c", '1', '0', 0)
putchar('1');putchar('0');putchar('\0');
putchar('1');putchar('0');putchar(0);
```

What is the difference between printing `"\0"` and `'\0'`?

Comment: In the ASCII encoding, `'\0'` has the value 0x00.  So, `'\0'` has the *single* char value of 0x00.  A string literal, `"\0"` has 2 values.  The first is 0 (by the above definition) and the second is 0 (because that's the termination value).  When using `printf`, single characters should have the `%c` format and string literals should have the `%s` format.

Comment: Does the wording say to output a string?  If just outputting text no zero terminator should be needed.  It would help if you posted the exact wording.

Comment: I assume this is a question in a test. Can you walk us though how you reason about it?

Comment: As for "_What is the difference between printing `"\0"` and `'\0'`?_" - It depends. If you do `printf("%s", "\0");` you will not print anything - even though `"\0"` is a `char[2]`, while a `'\0'` is a `char` and `putchar('\0');` or `printf("%c", '\0');` will actually send the `\0` out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your online testing system is expecting to see the character sequence `{'1', '0'}`, but you are sending it the sequence `{'1', '0', NUL }`.  You're trying to print the string terminator in addition to the string characters.

The string `"10"` is *internally represented* as the character sequence `{'1', '0', NUL}`, but when you display it with `printf( "%s", "10" );`, that trailing `0` isn't written to the output stream.  The terminator is only there to mark the end of the string - it's never displayed or copied.

Answer (score 5):

C-style strings end at the first null character. so the line

> `printf("%c%c\0", '1', '0')`

is equivalent to `printf("%c%c", '1', '0')` and the second null character in the original version (the one implicitly added by the compiler) is never looked at. Similarly, your other two working approaches output a `'1'` followed by a `'0'` and nothing else.

(The fourth version is a little different since the null character is in the last parameter instead of the first, but the principle is the same. That version is equivalent to `printf("%c%c%s", '1', '0', "")`.)

The versions that fail force a null character to the output by presenting it as an independent character, rather than being part of a string.

> What is the difference between printing `"\0"` and `'\0'`?

Printing `"\0"` is the same as printing `""` since the null character ends the string (it's not part of the output). Printing `'\0'` will actually output the null character.